# How to open and run devenv \ build command in Developer Command Prompt for VS2013?

Tags: c#, batch-file, build, command-prompt, devenv

I would like to build a VS 2013 project from the command line.

After manually open the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013", changing the directory to the project directory and inserting the following command

```
devenv myproject.csproj /build
```

the project is successfully built.

The problem is that I would like to do this from a C# function. I tried lot of things but none worked out.

When doing it manually I start the command prompt from a shortcut. The shortcut actually runs a `.bat` file that sets up the environment so you can run commands like `devenv` from the command prompt.
this is the code I am running

```
string runDevEnv = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE>devenv.com ";
string projectPath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CodedUITestProject2\CodedUITestProject2\CodedUITestProject2.csproj" ;
string makeString = "\"";
string slashc = "/c ";
string makebuild = " /build";
string compileProject = slashc + runDevEnv + makeString + projectPath + makeString + makebuild;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", compileProject);
```

Comment: Please tell us *what* you tried and what happened, rather than just "I tried a lot of things." Also, is there any reason you want to run Visual Studio rather than just `msbuild`? You probably want the `Process` class to launch `cmd.exe`.

Comment: the project I am trying to compile is a windows phone codedUI project. and for what i could read, only devenv can compile it. I tried manually to run msbuild and vstest.console.exe and could not compile the project. only devenv successfully compiled the project.

Comment: Well I'd certainly *expect* msbuild to be able to handle it. Again, you should explain everything you've tried and what's gone wrong within your question.

Comment: so let me put it in a different way: how do i open command line, change directory to a desired one and run devenv myproject.csproj /build command, all this in csharp, because i tried using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",compileProject) where compileProject has entire command. also tried startinfo with process.start also nothing happens, the project is not compiled

Comment: You don't "open a command line" - you run cmd.exe in the right directory to start with (you can set the working directory) and use `/c` to specify the command to run.

Comment: Well I'm certainly trying to, but you're not providing much in the way of diagnostics - did you include the `/c` flag in your `compileProject` string? A short but complete example (in your question, not in comments) would make it easier to help you. I suggest you write sample code to run some arbitrary batch file which just echoes a message to a file. That's easier to test than a full build.

Comment: added code I am trying now without results

Comment: As I said, I'd suggest running a batch file instead. I've got that working with similar code. Note that you're currently not putting quotes around `runDevEnv`, which may well be causing problems.

Comment: @JonSkeet I really appreciate your efforts, thank you very much, I am just very frustrated, trying getting this code compiled for two days now, have tried everything I found.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok I got something: i put the following in a batch file:"CD /d C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
devenv.exe "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CodedUITestProject2\CodedUITestProject2\CodedUITestProject2.csproj" \build" and then executed this code with c sharp, but then another instance of VS was opened. when running from command line the project is compiled but VS does not starts. so maybe you know a way to run this from batch file but that does not open VS?

Comment: As I said before, `devenv.com` is usually the solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easier to create a batch file to call devenv (if you really need to) but otherwise, I suspect it's just a matter of how you're quoting - and that you've got a `>` in your path to `devenv.exe`. Try:

```
string devEnv = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe";
string projectPath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CodedUITestProject2\CodedUITestProject2\CodedUITestProject2.csproj" ;
string compileProject = string.Format("/c \"{0}\" \"{1}\" /build",
    devEnv, projectPath);
Process.Start("CMD.exe", compileProject);
```

(As noted in comments, you may well want to use `devenv.com` instead of `devenv.exe`, to prevent Visual Studio itself from starting up. If you can possibly use `msbuild` instead, that would clearly be better - I know that isn't working for you immediately, but it would be worth investigating why instead of abandoning it.)

Comment: I tried to create a batch file, the issue with this is that VS IDE opens when running devenv command from batch file, and i need it silent

Comment: @Limbo: Try using `devenv.com` instead of `devenv.exe` then - I believe that's what it's for.

Comment: @Limbo: It's not exactly clear what that is. I doubt that *nothing* happens... is an exception thrown? Does a command line window pop up briefly (it does for me)? What are you running this from anyway? (A web app? Command line app? something else?) And have you tried using `devenv.com`. I'm afraid I have limited time to keep trying to get more information here...

Comment: when using devenv.com (windows 8.1) appears the big message "this app can't run on your pc", what is interesting is that before some of my experiments, i was able to build with devenv.com and suddenly this message started appearing

Comment: @Limbo: That's bizarre - it's working fine for me, still on Windows 8.1... you should edit your question with more details of exactly how you're running that, etc.

Comment: i am running this from a console application, it runs, a console is opened, and then exit, no exception, no error, but also not project compilation

Comment: @Limbo: Try running with `/k` instead of `/c` - that way you'll see what's in the command window (it'll stay up) instead of it popping down.